# Array to string conversion?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel 5.4 for my project and I need to pass mulitple id.

My view blade code:-

```
 @if($test)
 {!! Form::model($test, ['route' => ['test.update', ['1','2','3']], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
@else
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['test.store', ['1','2']]]) !!}
@endif
```

My route file code:-

```
 Route::resource('project/{projectId?}/activity/{activityId}/test', 'Project\Task\TaskController');
```

[image]

Comment: and what error you are facing

Comment: array to string conversion

Comment: What does $test return ?

Comment: I dont use collective, but I think the problem is pretty self explanatory, which variable is it complaining about that it cant convert to a string? I think your problem is either that the resource controller method is trying to do something with that array that its not supposed to, or you are trying to output something in your form the way its not supposed to. I will spin up a test site and pull in laravel collective if no one sovles this in the next few minutes.

Comment: Make a screenshot of your error and update

Comment: When passing the variables like you are it's not possible as you are trying to pass all of the ids as an array to a get variables. You should post these in your form. Maybe you could pass them through hidden form fields?

Comment: Yes I can understand what you can say @Chris But I need the id in route

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make url(to which you are saying string) from `Form::open` where you are passing array params. Change your array to `key=>value` pair to get right url

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['test.store', ['projectId'=>'1','activityId'=>'2']]]) !!}
```

Comment: @PawanDongol : first check what route:list you are getting ?

Comment: I will checked all route list by artisan command php artisan route:list it's ok.